# Call python function from node.js

Tags: python, node.js, node-modules

I would like to call python functions from node.js. I have found [python-shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell). But as far as I understand it can only run a full python script.

I have some logic (loading a huge file) which takes about 2 minutes. I would like to run it and then call python functions from node so that the file is loaded only once.

```py
# load a huge file takes 2min
model = xyz.load(path)

# function using that model
def doSomething(id):
    # some logic using the model
    return model.get(id)
```

How can I repeatedly call `doSomething()` without loading the file each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a solution to this using python-shell. Details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223084/continuously-exchange-data-using-python-shell).

Answer (score 0):

It is *in theory* possible to load a Python interpreter into another process and then interact with that, but it's not easy if there isn't a package for it already. You probably already checked for that.

If at all possible, figure out all the things you need to do in Python beforehand, pass a list to the script, and return the results as a list back to Node.js. That way you only need to run the script once.

If that's not possible, you could start your Python script as a separate process and make your Node.js program communicate with it using some protocol, maybe something as simple as JSON over stdin/stdout. Then your Node.js program can send commands to the Python program and the Python program can reply back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use some middleware like ZeroMQ. It's basically sockets made easy (the atomic unit being sent is the whole *message*, not the packet). It is available both for [node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zmq) and [python](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io).

The typical REQ/REP client/server is just a few lines long.

E.g.: the python server:

```
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

while True:
    #  Wait for next request from client
    message = socket.recv()
    print("Received request: %s" % message)

    #  Do some 'work'
    time.sleep(1)

    #  Send reply back to client
    socket.send(b"World")
```

and the node.js client:

```
var zmq = require('zmq');

// socket to talk to server
console.log("Connecting to hello world server…");
var requester = zmq.socket('req');

var x = 0;
requester.on("message", function(reply) {
  console.log("Received reply", x, ": [", reply.toString(), ']');
  x += 1;
  if (x === 10) {
    requester.close();
    process.exit(0);
  }
});

requester.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  console.log("Sending request", i, '…');
  requester.send("Hello");
}

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
  requester.close();
});
```